# Tendancy at Fixed Effects; Significance at LSmeans

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, biostatistics

I have successfully experienced every young scientist's worst nightmare! Letting a paper sit while starting a job, then trying to remember what everything means. Of course I am in a different city than my favorite statistics book, so hopefully someone can answer this for me!

I am running a mixed model and have a tendency (P=0.08) then looking at the fixed effects of block by diet, but there are significant differences when looking at the differences of least squared means. How do I translate these findings coherently?

Comment: Can you provide a better description of your data, what question you are trying to answer, your model and output?